# How do I format a messge received from a server?

Tags: java, android

I have a very simple client server application working. At the moment when I send a message to the server it sends back some information, what I would like to do is get the android (Client) to format the message it receives, as in put one part of the message in a textview/editText and the other half in a different one. Is there any way of doing this?

Any help is much appreciated and thanks in advance.

So i will send the line 50126057 from the android and the server will send back "prd|50126057|12bars|5|199|1|[)" It sends this as a string.

Comment: Could you give a bit more information about the message you receive? For example is it xml or a regular string? Are the things in the string seperated by anything? Stuff like that...

Comment: If you can identify "one part" and "the other half", it's possible to put them into different text boxes, why wouldn't it?

Comment: @ClassStacker I never said it wasn't possible I was asking is there any way to do it.

Comment: @WereWolfBoy I have just updated it for you.

Comment: @user2072623 the answer iambmelton gave would be correct than. You would need to change response.split(" "); to response.split("|");. I think..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep! You can, for instance split a String using an expression (with regex) or by using substsr().

```
String response = "Hello, World";
String[] words = response.split(" ");
TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id....);
TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id....);
tv1.setText(words[0]);
tv2.setText(words[1]);
```